# UITextView didEndEditing isn't called on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, uitextview, dismiss

The method `textViewDidEndEditing` is not called when you dismiss the keyboard on the iPad with the button in the right corner at the button. However, i want the method to be called so that I basically can access the written text.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)note {
    // Whatever you want
}
```

Don't forget to call `removeObserver:` in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I also have a `textField` which got the method `textFieldShouldReturn`that doesn't work anymore … Any solution to that? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question. Finish this one and open a new question with details about your texField.